# Retrieving metadata album cover from media files in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, metadata, scenebuilder

I've created a MediaPlayer which plays the music chosen by the user when he selects the song from the listview. I'm trying to display the metadata of each track whenever it's selected including the album cover (Which I was unable to display).
[image]

And here's my list view:

[image]

The album cover should be displayed in the imageview I've created:

```
  @FXML
     ListView<File> listV ;
 @FXML
    private ImageView imv;
 File songs;
    URI path;
     Media test;
       MediaPlayer finale;

songs = listV.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
         path = songs .toURI();
     test = new Media(Paths.get(path).toUri().toString());
     finale = new MediaPlayer(test); 
ObservableMap<String,Object> meta_data= finale.getMedia().getMetadata();

     meta_data.addListener(new MapChangeListener<String,Object>(){
          @Override
          public void onChanged(Change<? extends String, ? extends Object> ch) {  
     
             if(ch.wasAdded()){

                   String key=ch.getKey();
                   Object value=ch.getValueAdded();

             switch(key){
               case "album":
                   albumT.setText("Album: "+value.toString());
                   break;
               case "artist":  
                   artistF.setText("Artist: "+value.toString());
                   break;
               case "title":
                   nameF.setText("Title: "+value.toString());
                   break;
               case "year":
                   YearT.setText("Year: "+value.toString());
                   break;
               case "image":
                   imv.setImage((Image)value);
                   break;
           }
             
              }
          }
     });
```

Can anyone tell me why the pictures ain't displaying? Thanks!

Comment: Log the changes, particularly the key and the type of the value. Are you sure there is an 
`"image"` key in the metadata map, and if so, is the type of the value `Image`?

Comment: Sir I just figured out the problem. It appears that the cover art that was displayed wasn't actually in the metadata. I basically downloaded the mp3 song online and I thought it had the cover art. It works now thank you though!